# Visualforce to Lightning Component

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to convert this to a lightning component.

```
<apex:page standardController="School__c" extensions="SchoolController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" lightningStylesheets="true" >


<apex:form id="form">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <div id="outputNote">
        <apex:outputText value="{!pnotes.Notes__c}" escape="false"/>
    </div>
    <div id="inputNote">
        <apex:inputField id="notes" value="{!pnotes.Notes__c}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-controls">
        <button type="button" class="edit-btn ltngButton">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="cancel-btn ltngButton">Cancel</button>
        <apex:commandButton styleClass="save-btn ltngButton save-button" value="Save Note" action="{!save}"/>
    </div>
</apex:form>
```

This is a basically a notes pages for each record dependent on user.  It's basically only the running user can see it.

Any idea or guidance on I can convert this VF page to Lightning component?

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please see [ask], and help us with an [edit] to define the specific problem and what a good solution would look like (remembering that we can't write the code for you).

Comment: There’s no magic bullet for a 1-1 conversion here. You’ll need to account for what your current code does and how it should behave when using lightning component. Not only the UI part needs to be rewritten but also the apex behind this.

Comment: As a starting point... I would suggest looking at the lightning:recordEditForm/lightning-record-edit-form component in the [Component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) to see if that meets your needs. The examples in the Component Reference may be useful to give you some context and understanding of how LIghtning Components work.